# Size of JSON object being sent through Websockets

Tags: javascript, json, web-applications, websocket, benchmarking

Is there a way of getting the size of JSON being sent through websockets? I'm sending messages of variable length every 20ms and I would like to know their size for optimization purposes.

I've managed to find out the length of the message through the websockets frame tab of the network section in Chrome Developer Tools. Is there something similar where I can view the message size? Or maybe I have to write my own function in javascript?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: for fear of being unproductive, my network tab shows content size

Comment: @NickKnudson Thanks but I don't think content size for the websockets request only shows the initial request size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [detailed guide](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/) on how you could enable WebSocket frames debugging this in Google Chrome. I will post them here in case the blog post goes offline:

1. Be sure that your Chrome version is 20+.
2. Navigate to the Echo demo, hosted on the websocket.org site.
3. Turn on the Chrome Developer Tools.
4. Click Network, and to filter the traffic shown by the Dev Tools, click WebSockets (all the way on the bottom).
5. In the Echo demo, click Connect.
6. Click www.websocket.org on the left, representing the WebSocket connection.
7. Make sure you’re on the Headers tab. This tab shows the WebSocket handshake.
8. Click the Send button in the Echo demo.
9. THIS STEP IS IMPORTANT: To see the WebSocket frames in the Chrome Developer Tools, under Name/Path, click the echo.websocket.org entry, representing your WebSocket connection. This refreshes the main panel on the right and makes the WebSocket Frames tab show up with the actual WebSocket message content.
   Note: Every time you send or receive new messages, you have to refresh the main panel by clicking on the echo.websocket.org entry on the left.

Another possibility is to use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I did come across this web page but does the `length` stat refer to the size of the message or just it's length in characters? Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking at the WebSocket frame (step 9) it refers to the size of the message being sent excluding the envelope.